# Storing Null value in asp.net cache

Tags: asp.net, caching

This question is somehow related to one that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967893/asp-net-cant-cache-null-value).
In order to avoid round trip to the database I am caching the database output but in case of a null value, asp.net cannot make the difference between a value not set and an actual NULL value. I was wondering if instead of checking for the cache value for a specified key , we could check if a key is in the cache . Maybe there is a way to get what keys are in the cache instead of looking for values. If not I would like to know how you would typically cache such data or if in fact caching it makes no sense.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you access the cache through your own wrapper function that converts a `null` into a `DBNull.Value` before storing.